# Creating list items after GET request is complete

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to figure out a more efficient away to create the list items in the DOM.

At the moment the list is created as each API request is made.

I'm pushing each object into its own Array, I would like to create the list once all the data has loaded.

Additionally i'm using Webpack and Babel.

```
let streamApi = 'https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/';
let twitchUsers = ['ESL_SC2', 'OgamingSC2', 'freecodecamp', 'noobs2ninjas', 'comster404'];
let streamByUser = [];

window.onload = function() {
    //Make a API request for each user and store in an array
    twitchUsers.map((user) => {
        fetch(streamApi + user, {method: 'GET'})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            streamByUser.push(json);
            let uL = document.getElementById("user-list");        
            let listItem = document.createElement("li");  
            listItem.className = "list-group-item";
            if (json.stream === null) {
                listItem.innerHTML = "null";
            } else {
                listItem.innerHTML = json.stream.channel.display_name;
            }
            uL.appendChild(listItem);
        });
    });

};
```

UPDATE:
All is working!

Comment: You are not returning from `twitchUser.map`. It should return the promise: `let streamByUser = twitchUsers.map((user) => {
  return fetch(streamApi + user, { method: 'GET' }).then(response => response.json());
});` More about [ES6 Arrow Function Here](https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read#leanpub-auto-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested but I hope it should work as expected.

```
const streamApi = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/";
const twitchUsers = [
  "ESL_SC2",
  "OgamingSC2",
  "freecodecamp",
  "noobs2ninjas",
  "comster404"
];
const twitchUsersStreams = twitchUsers.map(user =>
  fetch(streamApi + user, { method: "GET" }).then(res => res.json())
);

let streamByUser = [];
window.onload = function() {
  Promise
    .all(twitchUsersStreams)
    .then(everythingArray => {
      //do something with everythingArray after all the requests resolved
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // As soon as any of the 'fetch' results in promise rejection
    });
};
```

Comment: You should change all `let`'s into `const`'s except for the third.

Comment: @Roberrrt I just copy pasted OP's question and provided the answer from there. Lemme do that quick :)

Comment: Oh, nice, merely improving your answer. Keep up the good work!

Comment: I like this answer too.

Comment: Thanks, It's good for me to get my head around the Promise object. Its a pretty new concept for me

Comment: Nah, I'm getting undefined when I try using
`const twitchUsersStreams = twitchUsers.map(user =>
  fetch(streamApi + user, { method: "GET" }).then(res => res.json())
);`

Comment: You are not returning from `twitchUser.map`. It should return the promise: `let streamByUser = twitchUsers.map((user) => {
  return fetch(streamApi + user, { method: 'GET' }).then(response => response.json());
});` More about [ES6 Arrow Function Here](https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read#leanpub-auto-arrow-functions)

Comment: Ah silly me - Yes the single line arrow function returns it without including return statement. Thaanks @Lekhnath

Comment: @Lekhnath - Thanks for all your help. I'm still learning many JavaScript concepts - finally moving away from basic css/html pages and moving towards functioning webpps

Comment: @Nims I am glad I could help you, and best of luck for self exploration. (y)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this because I really like to decompose a task into small functions that reduce the need for inline comments and keep mutable state to a minimum.

```
const streamApi = 'https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/';
const twitchUsers = ['ESL_SC2', 'OgamingSC2', 'freecodecamp', 'noobs2ninjas', 'comster404'];

window.onload = async function () {
  const list = document.getElementById("user-list");
  const addToList = list.appendChild.bind(list);
  const twitchStreams = await fetchUsers(twitchUsers);
  twitchStreams.map(toListItem).forEach(addToList);
};

async function fetchUser(user) {
  const response = await fetch(`${streamApi}${user}`, {method: 'GET'});
  return response.json();
}

function fetchUsers(users) {
  return Promise.all(users.map(fetchUser));
}

function toListItem(user) {
  const listItem = document.createElement("li");  
  listItem.className = "list-group-item";
  listItem.innerHTML = user.stream !== null
    ? user.stream.channel.display_name
    : "null";
  return listItem;
}
```

Comment: `user` is undefined in `fetchUser` :)

Comment: Also `Promise.all` instead of `.All`

Comment: Thanks, TypeScript is making me lazy.

Comment: Thanks for your input :). It's so interesting to see the different ways the same task can be accomplished.

Comment: @Nims indeed it is. This was a fun question to answer and, with some StarCraft II streams as a datasource, well... I just couldn't resist taking a crack at it. :)

Comment: Thanks again @AluanHaddad